# Add an extra field on login form of Symfony's security component

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need validate an extra field while somebody tries to login. Instead of only trying to validate user+password, I need validate user+password+company, being company one  on the login form.

I've already looked into the Symfony's cookbooks but I didn't find anything suitable. I think the most accurate to what I need is this topic [How to Create a Custom Form Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html). But in this example it doesn't shows how to handle the value of the inputs on the form.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the FOSUserBundle? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle  This is a very good, active bundle that will support most of your user authentication needs. If you want to add an extra field to the FOSUB forms this can do it by  overwriting the forms: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md.

Comment: In fact I'm using FOSUserBundle. I've already gave up because I don't found any resource about my problem... But ok. If I override the form, how do I tell FOSUserBundle to validate the new field against the database?

Comment: For this you need to write a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), an example of how this can be accomplished is the [Adding invitation to registration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adding_invitation_registration.md). I did something similar a few months ago, and I remember that this example was incomplete, not sure if it has been updated since I used it.